# How to create a drop down menu in MFC for WINCE

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, mfc, windows-ce

I have the following code in a win32 app that shows a drop down menu on clicking a button. However, this does not work in WinCE as MENUINFO is not defined. Is there any way I can get around this? I need to view a drop down menu on clicking a button, and the name appearing on the button changes depending on the option on the menu.

```
void CTestDlg::OnBnClickedBtnMenu()  
{  
    if( NULL == m_PopUpMenu.m_hMenu )  
      {  
     m_PopUpMenu.SetMenuDimension( 120 );

        m_PopUpMenu.CreatePopupMenu();
        m_PopUpMenu.AppendMenu( MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED | MF_OWNERDRAW, 697, _T("A") );
        m_PopUpMenu.AppendMenu( MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED | MF_OWNERDRAW, 697, _T("B") );
        m_PopUpMenu.AppendMenu( MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED | MF_OWNERDRAW, 697, _T("C") );
        m_PopUpMenu.AppendMenu( MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED | MF_OWNERDRAW, 697, _T("D") );

        MENUINFO MenuInfo;
        memset( &MenuInfo, 0, sizeof(MENUINFO) );
        MenuInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MENUINFO);
        MenuInfo.fMask = MIM_STYLE;
        MenuInfo.dwStyle = MNS_NOTIFYBYPOS;

        m_PopUpMenu.SetMenuInfo( &MenuInfo );
}
```